# not getting milliseconds difference between two dates

Tags: swift, nscalendar

In my app I need some kind of timer like countdown. Like for Next match there is  1 year 2 month 6 days 23 minutes 24 seconds and 5 milliseconds remaining.

For this I am using this code:

```
extension DateComponentsFormatter {
    func difference(from fromDate: Date, to toDate: Date) -> String? {
        self.allowedUnits = [.year,.month,.day,.hour, .minute, .second ,.nanosecond]
        self.maximumUnitCount = 8
        self.unitsStyle = .full
        return self.string(from: fromDate, to: toDate)
    }
}
```

But I am not  getting milliseconds.

Here is what I am getting:

```
["24 years", " 8 months", " 20 days", " 12 hours", " 2 minutes", " 48 seconds"]
```

I need milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a `DateComponentsFormatter` to format milliseconds. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter/1410216-allowedunits), only these calendar units are allowed:

- `year`
- `month`
- `weekOfMonth`
- `day`
- `hour`
- `minute`
- `second`

You will have to format this yourself, by getting the `TimeInterval` between the dates, get the fractional part of the time interval, and format that.

Here is an idea of what this would look like.

```
extension DateComponentsFormatter {
    func difference(from fromDate: Date, to toDate: Date) -> String? {
        self.allowedUnits = [NSCalendar.Unit.second]
        allowsFractionalUnits = true
        self.maximumUnitCount = 8
        self.unitsStyle = .full
        guard let firstPart = self.string(from: fromDate, to: toDate) else { return nil }
        let milliseconds = abs(toDate.timeIntervalSince(fromDate)).remainder(dividingBy: 1) * 1000
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        guard let secondPart = numberFormatter.string(from: milliseconds as NSNumber) else { return nil }
        return "\(firstPart) \(secondPart) milliseconds"
    }
}

let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.difference(from: Date(), to: Date().addingTimeInterval(0.5))
```